# Python/Pytorch Dataloader in complicated directory

Tags: python, machine-learning, directory, pytorch

For a particular project, I have to use Python Dataloader for a series of .nifti files (specifically the OASIS-BRAINS2 dataset)
However each of the scans are in a directory tree, stored in google drive and being accessed using google colab with the following format
Patient-001

---Scan-1

---Scan-2

---Scan-3

---Scan-4

Patient-002

---Scan-1

---Scan-2

---Scan-3

---Scan-4
etc.
And there is a separate .csv file which contains their status, which I wish to train a neural network on. I have the network already set up and ready to train, as well as preprocessing and transforms for the data. What would the best way to load all of this information into the Network for training.
All of the datasets that I have used previously have existing dataloaders.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to create a flat directory structure, e.g. two files `data` and `labels` where each data files and label files correspond on a one-to-one mapping. This will allow you to use an off-the-shelf pytorch dataset/dataloader class.

To achieve this one-to-one flat directory structure, you can either:

1. Copy files from each subdirectory into a single new flat `data` directory, and similarly for the labels. This will work and be simple to do if your data size is small
2. If your data is large enough that you don't want to copy it, you can create symbolic links in the flat directory structure to the original file locations. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322794/how-do-i-create-a-symbolic-link-using-a-batch-script-in-windows) for Windows and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/633605/how-to-create-symbolic-links-to-all-files-class-of-files-in-a-directory) for Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, the data is actually being stored in google drive, and being accessed in google colab. How would I create such a flat directory, such that the files would be called Patient-1-Scan-1, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If creating a new structure for your data is not viable, you can always extend the [torch.util.data.Dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) class.
This allow you to manage directly the loading procedure. You can follow [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) in the official Pytorch wiki.